# not able to read the parameter from a xml after doing xslt transformation

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report name="DB232  Report">
<rptHdr>
<exchNam>CAG</exchNam>
<rptCod>RP202</rptCod>
<rptNam>ory Report</rptNam>
<membLglNam>XYZ  Germany</membLglNam>
<membId>XY</membId>
<rptPrntEffDat>2013-07-18T23:59:00</rptPrntEffDat>
<rptPrntRunDat>2013-07-18</rptPrntRunDat>
</rptHdr>
<reportNameGrp>
</Report>
```

Now I am writing xslt with respect to xslt 1.0 i have developed the below xslt now from the above xml I want tit read the parameter exchNam which value is CAG , my xslt is shown below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:template match="/Report">
    <pprexMessageObject>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/Report/rptHdr/rptNam='ory Report'">
                 <xsl:call-template name="rexReportHeader_template">
                    <xsl:with-param name="reportheader" select="/Report/rptHdr" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
    </EurexMessageObject>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="rexReportHeader_template">
        <xsl:param name="reportheader" />
        <rexMessageObject>
        <exchNam>
        <xsl:value-of select="$reportheader/exchNam"/>
        </exchNam>
        </pprexMessageObject>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but after transformation i am still not able to view the value of exchNam parameter please advise what went wrong in my xslt

folks please advise

Comment: Try correcting your XML and XSLT to be valid XMLs.. some elements do not have matching end tags.

Comment: @CS Lingamurthy Thanks for the advise I have edited now

Answer (score 1):

1- "reportNameGrp" has no end tag. Correct it.

2- Delete the first '/' of all the match, select and test parameters. Once you tell to the template to match Report tag you dont need to add it to the XML path.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:template match="Report">
    <pprexMessageObject>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="rptHdr/rptNam='ory Report'">
                 <xsl:call-template name="rexReportHeader_template">
                    <xsl:with-param name="reportheader" select="rptHdr" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
    </EurexMessageObject>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="rexReportHeader_template">
        <xsl:param name="reportheader" />
        <rexMessageObject>
        <exchNam>
        <xsl:value-of select="$reportheader/exchNam"/>
        </exchNam>
        </pprexMessageObject>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```